# Multiple Image URLs getting fetched as single URL in GSC for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

I'm facing 404 error in Google Search Console for multiple URLs. After checking, I found that GSC is fetching multiple image URLs as one URL for product images.

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image]

As you can see, multiple URLs are being combined into one, which is resulting in a 404 error.

Here is one of the problematic links:

https://theaugustco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AA20347AAArtboard-3.jpg,https:/theaugustco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AA20347AAArtboard-5.jpg,https:/theaugustco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AA20347AAArtboard-2-1.jpg,https:/theaugustco.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AA20347AAArtboard-4.jpg